# Discord Self-Bot: Direct messaging a user when joining a server/guild

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, chatbot

I am trying to create a bot to run through my personal discord account, and direct message people when they join a specific discord server I am in. However, my on_member_join(member) method is not running when a member joins a server (not printing "registered" in terminal). I am curious how to make the bot listen for a specific server or just register this event in general. Note on_connect() and spam() both function properly.

```
import discord
import asyncio
import requests
from discord.ext import commands
yer=commands.Bot(command_prefix="!",help_command=None,self_bot=True)
token="TOKEN"

class SelfBot(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self,yer):
        self.yer=yer

   @yer.command()
   async def spam(ctx):
        for i in range(50):
            await ctx.send("Hello!")
            await asyncio.sleep(0.7)

    @yer.event
    async def on_connect():
        await yer.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle,activity=discord.Game("Game"))

   @yer.event
   async def on_member_join(member):
       print("registered")

yer.run(token,bot=False)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Self bots are not authorized on Discord and can get your account banned.](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-)

> Discord's API provides a separate type of user account dedicated to automation, called a bot account. Bot accounts can be created through the applications page, and are authenticated using a token (rather than a username and password). Unlike the normal OAuth2 flow, bot accounts have full access to all API routes without using bearer tokens, and can connect to the Real Time Gateway. **Automating normal user accounts (generally called "self-bots") outside of the OAuth2/bot API is forbidden, and can result in an account termination if found.**

You won't be able to do those kind of things with the official `discord.py` module and I'm not sure that you will be able to receive help on StackOverflow if you choose something else to build a self-bot.